# Count number of zeros in registry in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a measuring device (connected to Raspberry) which outputs a series of zeros and ones. Without penetrating into the very essence of the measured value, Raspberry reads the state of input 1 thousand times per second. Measurement is that every second I have to count the number of zeros that have occurred in the last 30 seconds. Hence I have a string of 30,000 bits in which I have to count the number of zeros every second.
Since of course the SD card is not suitable for this, I created a ramdisk (64 Mb) where the data can be saved at high speed without storing anything on the SD.
I have a request to the Colleagues for advice. I would like to write a program in Python that counts these zeros, but I completely have no idea what algorithm to handle this and Python will handle it. It seems that you need to create some 30,000 bit software shift register and count the number of zeros in this registry every second.
Do Colleagues have an idea for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

First - try to keep the data in memory, do not write it to a file

Second - such problems are typically solved with a sliding window. for every new value that is added to the sum there is an old one subtracted. for this you have to keep all 30.000 values in a double ended queue. quite a lot.

Third - there is a constraint you mentioned, the result will be requested every second only. you may sum all 1.000 values per second without keeping the values themselves. every second you then handle this partial sum like you did with the values before, you push it to the queue. the deque length required is only 30. memory footprint problem solved.

Fourth - if you really need some file persistence write the partial sums and queue status either every second or per value.

Example code - not thoroughly tested

```
from collections import deque

class Sliding_sum():
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
        self.sum = 0
        self.queue = deque()
    def update(self, value):
        self.queue.append(value)
        self.sum += value
        if len(self.queue) > self.length:
            v = self.queue.popleft()
            self.sum -= v
    def get_sum(self):
        if len(self.queue) == self.length:
            return self.sum
        else:
            # different action required?
            return self.sum

class Ticked_sum():
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
        self.sliding_sum = Sliding_sum(length)
        self.partial_sum = 0
    def update(self, value):
        self.partial_sum += value
    def tick(self):
        self.sliding_sum.update(self.partial_sum)
        self.partial_sum = 0
    def get_sum(self):
        return self.sliding_sum.get_sum()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ts = Ticked_sum(2) # 30 in your case
    ts.update(1)
    ts.update(1)
    ts.update(1)
    ts.update(1) # 1.000 updates
    ts.tick() # ticking and requesting sum every second
    print(ts.get_sum())
    ts.update(1)
    ts.update(1)
    ts.update(1)
    ts.update(1)
    ts.tick()
    print(ts.get_sum())
```

where you get your tick event from is up to you. counting to 1.000, by clock or derived from the clocked request are the options.